# SQL - Not able to use basic functions

Tags: sql

```
SELECT [UnitId], [ParkName] AS Park_Name_Vestas,
       [TravelHours],
       [UnitLocation] + ' ' + [SBU] Location_SBU,
       [TotalEmployees] + 20 "new no_of Employees",
       MAX(aa.TravelHours) as Maximum
FROM aa.aa
```

This works fine if I remove the `max()` function, but with `max()` function or any other function it gives the following error:

> Column 'aa.aa.UnitId' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: If you use aggregate function(max, sum, count...) then you must add GROUP BY columns.

Comment: Your code is not MySQL, so I changed the tag to "sql".  Feel free to add the database you are actually using (which I would guess is SQL Server).

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule is: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include all the columns in select list to the `GROUP BY` and obviously use `group by`. You can as well get the grouping first and then perform a simple join like

```
SELECT [UnitId], 
       [ParkName] AS Park_Name_Vestas, 
       [TravelHours], 
       [UnitLocation] + ' ' + [SBU] Location_SBU,
       [TotalEmployees] + 20 "new no_of Employees", 
       xx.Maximum
FROM aa 
JOIN (SELECT [UnitId], MAX(aa.TravelHours) as Maximum
      FROM aa
      GROUP BY [UnitId] ) xx ON aa.[UnitId] = xx.[UnitId];
```

Answer (score 1):

Window functions may do what you want.  If you want all the original rows, then you can use the `over` clause:

```
SELECT [UnitId], [ParkName] AS Park_Name_Vestas, 
       [TravelHours], [UnitLocation] + ' ' + [SBU] Las ocation_SBU,
       [TotalEmployees] + 20 "new no_of Employees",
       MAX(aa.TravelHours) OVER () as Maximum
FROM aa.aa;
```

This gives the maximum over all the data.  If you want the maximum for particular groups, then use the `PARTITION BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY id`.
id would be your Primary key

Comment: That won't be sufficient. All other columns in the SELECT must be in GROUP BY for MS SQL Server or Access, which this appears to be.